# How to dynamically hide a drop-down option in relation to database values?

Tags: hide

Is it possible to hide an option from a drop-down list if a certain number of it has been completed in the database?

`

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>تسجيل رغبات التدريب الميداني ذكور</title>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="icon" href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WNOkwJlJoE4/X7RNQff4MxI/AAAAAAAABJo/FyrtM9AjWW45HP39L_eYnT9LLiqFHSVnACNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/%25D8%25AE%25D8%25AE%25D8%25AE.png">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

body{

background-color: #fafaff;

}

#customers {

  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

  border-collapse: collapse;

  width: 100%;

}

 td, #customers th {

  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  padding: 8px;

}

 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

 tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

 th {

  padding-top: 12px;

  padding-bottom: 12px;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #1E90FF;

  color: white;

}

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-md-7">

        <div>

            <br>

        <form method="post">

       

        <div type="submit" name="home" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="home()">الصفحة الرئيسية</div>

</form>

</div>

            <div class="card mt-5">

                <div class="card-header text-center" >

                    <h4> تسجيل رغبات التدريب الميداني ذكور</h4>

                </div>

                <div class="card-body">

                    <form action="" method="GET">

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-8">

                                <input type="number" placeholder="الرقم القومي " name="stud_idd" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['stud_idd'])){echo $_GET['stud_idd'];} ?>"  minlength="14" maxlength="14" class="form-control" required>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <center> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >بحث</button></center>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </form>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <hr>

                            <?php 

                               require 'connect.php';

                                if($_GET['stud_idd'])

                                {

                                    $stud_idd = $_GET['stud_idd'];

                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM male WHERE idd = '$stud_idd'";

                                    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) )

                                    {

                                        foreach($query_run as $row)

                                        {

                                            ?>

                                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                            <div class="form-group mb-3">

                                                <label for="">الاسم</label>

                                                <input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $row['name']; ?>" class="form-control"   readonly>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group mb-3">

                                            <label for="">النوع</label>

                                            <input type="text" name="sex" value="<?= $row['sex']; ?>" class="form-control"   readonly>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group mb-3" style="display: none;">

                                                <label for="">الرقم القومي</label>

                                                <input type="text" name="idd" value="<?= $row['idd']; ?>" class="form-control"   readonly>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group mb-3">

                                            <label for="">رقم الهاتف</label>

                                            <input type="number" name="phone" value="<? echo $phone=$_POST["phone"]; ?>" class="form-control" max="01599999999" min="01000000000"  required>

                                            </div>

                                                <div class="form-group mb-3">

                                                <label for="text">المكان</label>

                                                <select  name="l1" id="country"  class="form-control" placeholder="المكان" required >

                                                 <option value="">اختر</option>

                                                </select>

                                                

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group mb-3">

                                                <label for="text">الرغبة</label>

                                                <select  name="l2" id="state" class="form-control" placeholder="الرغبة" required >

                                                 <option value="">اختر</option>

                                                </select>

                                                

                                            </div>

                                                

                                                    <center> <button type="submit" name="signup" class="btn btn-primary" >سجل الان</button></center>

                                        </div>

           

           

           

           

           

                                

                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                        <br>

                                        </form>

                                            <?php

                                        }

                                    }

                                    else

                                    {

                                        echo "قم بكتابة رقمك القومي  ";

                                    }

                                }

                               

                            

                                if(isset($_POST["signup"])){

                                    $name=$_POST["name"];

                                   $idd=$_POST["idd"];

                                   $phone=$_POST["phone"];

                                   $l1=$_POST["l1"];

                                   $l2=$_POST["l2"];

                                   $sex=$_POST["sex"];

                                   

                                   //select  where field name=email

                                   

                                   $select="select * from work where  idd ='$idd'";

                                   $query=  mysqli_query($con, $select);

                                   

                                   

                                   $select1="select * from work where  'دار المسنين' ='$l2'";

                                   $query1=  mysqli_query($con, $select1);

                                   

                                    

                                   if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

                                       

                                       echo '<script>alert("المستخدم موجود من قبل");</script>';

                                       }

                           

                                   

                          

                    

                                   



                                   else{

                                       //email does not exists

                                       

                                       $insert="INSERT INTO work ( `name`, `idd`, `phone`, `l1`, `l2` ,`sex`) "

                                               . "values('$name','$idd', '$phone','$l1','$l2','$sex')";

                                       

                                       $query2=  mysqli_query($con, $insert);

                                       

                                                  echo '<script>alert("تم تسجيل الرغبة بنجاح");window.location.assign("home.html");</script>';

                                       

                                   

                                       

                                   }

                                }

                            ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('country');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)

 {

  var html_code = '';

  $.getJSON('data1.json', function(data){

   html_code += 'اختر ...';

   $.each(data, function(key, value){

    if(id == 'country')

    {

     if(value.parent_id == '0')

     {

      html_code += ''+value.name+'';

     }

    }

    else

    {

     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)

     {

      html_code += ''+value.name+'';

     }

    }

   });

   $('#'+id).html(html_code);

  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#country', function(){

  var country_id = $(this).val();

  if(country_id != '')

  {

   load_json_data('state', country_id);

  }

  

 });

});

function home(){

window.location.assign("https://social-work.rf.gd/training/home.html");

}

`

Is it possible to hide an option from a drop-down list if a certain number of it has been completed in the database?